# creating simple thread in swift gives error

Tags: ios, iphone, multithreading, swift

I'm trying to create a simple thread in swift  and on button click starting but it throws an error

```
"**Cannot find an initializer for type 'NSThread' that accepts an argument list of type ('target:ViewControllerm-> ())'**
```

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var isSet = true          
    let thread123 = NSThread(target: self, selector: "myFunc", object: nil)

    func myFunc() {
    }

    @IBAction func btnClickEvent(sender: AnyObject) {
        // starting thread
        thread12.start()   
    }

}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the error message is quite confusing. try rewriting it as

```
let thread123:NSThread

init() {
    thread123 = NSThread(target: self, selector: "myFunc", object: nil)
}
```

and you get a cleaner error message that shows you that self isn't there yet

SO:

```
let thread123:NSThread

init() {
    super.init()
    thread123 = NSThread(target: self, selector: "myFunc", object: nil)
}
```

now the constant isn't initialised before calling super.. also a nogo

so

```
var thread123:NSThread!

init() {
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    thread123 = NSThread(target: self, selector: "myFunc", object: nil)
}
```

OR SHORT AND SWEET

```
lazy var thread123:NSThread = NSThread(target: self, selector: "myFunc", object: nil)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to replace this line

```
let thread123 = NSThread(target: self, selector: "myFunc", object: nil)
```

with

```
lazy var thread123:NSThread =
    {
        return NSThread(target: self, selector: "myFunc", object: nil)
    }()
```